# $P(A \cup B^{c})$ when $P(A) = P(B) = 1/3$, and $P(A \cap B) = 1/10$

Tags: probability, self-study

I think that I am looking for everything outside $B$. So why is the answer $23/30$ instead of $2/3$? Thanks

Comment: You are looking for everything either outside $B$ *or* inside $A$.

Comment: So this includes the intersection?

Comment: $A \cup B^c$ is the union of set $A$ and the complement of set $B$. This will include everything inside of $A$ and will also include everything outside of $B$.

Comment: Pictures are worth 1024 words.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually looking for everything outside $A^C B$, so what is $1-P(A^C B)$?

$P(B) = P(AB) + P(A^C B)$ so

$P(A^C B) = P(B) - P(AB) = \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{10}=\frac{7}{30}$

$1-P(A^C B) = 1 - \frac{7}{30} = \frac{23}{30}$